# 2 Player Games in OpenAI Retro

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been using OpenAI Retro for awhile, and I wanted to experiment with two player games. By two player games, I mean co-op games like "Tennis-Atari2600" or even Pong, where 2 agents are present in one environment.

There is a parameter for `players` in the OpenAI documentation, but setting this variable to `2` does nothing in terms of the game.

**How do you properly implement this? Can this even be done?** The end goal is to have 2 separate networks per one environment.